# sql server 2008 database merging with another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, merge

I have 2 sql server databases on two different remote servers. On day one, they were both exaclty the same. But over time, there are changes in both (different, tables, stored procs, views, etc..).

How do I merge them together, so I have one again - the same Database in both places?

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at [Red Gates SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm), if it's a big schema, it's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

with this script you compare two db :

```
USE Master
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'sp_CompareDB' and type = 'P')
DROP PROC sp_CompareDB
GO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- sp_CompareDB
-- 
-- The SP compares structures and data in 2 databases.
-- 1. Compares if all tables in one database have analog (by name) in second database
-- Tables not existing in one of databases won't be used for data comparing
-- 2. Compares if structures for tables with the same names are the same. Shows structural
-- differences like:
-- authors
-- Column Phone: in db1 - char(12), in db2 - char(14)
-- sales
-- Column Location not in db2
-- Tables, having different structures, won't be used for data comparing. However if the tables
-- contain columns of the same type and different length (like Phone in the example above) or
-- tables have compatible data types (have the same type in syscolumns - char and nchar, 
-- varchar and nvarchar etc) they will be allowed for data comparing.
-- 3. Data comparison itself. 
-- 3.1 Get information about unique keys in the tables. If there are unique keys then one of them
-- (PK is a highest priority candidate for this role) will be used to specify rows with
-- different data.
-- 3.2 Get information about all data columns in the table and form predicates that will be 
-- used to compare data.
-- 3.3 Compare data with the criteria:
-- a. if some unique keys from the table from first database do not exist in second db (only
-- for tables with a unique key)
-- b. if some unique keys from the table from second database do not exist in first db (only
-- for tables with a unique key)
-- c. if there are rows with the same values of unique keys and different data in other
-- columns (only for tables with a unique key)
-- d. if there are rows in the table from first database that don't have a twin in the 
-- table from second db
-- e. if there are rows in the table from second database that don't have a twin in the 
-- table from first db
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Parameters:
-- 1. @db1 - name of first database to compare
-- 2. @db2 - name of second database to compare
-- 3. @TabList - list of tables to compare. if empty - all tables in the databases should be
-- compared
-- 4. @NumbToShow - number of rows with differences to show. Default - 10.
-- 5. @OnlyStructure - flag, if set to 1, allows to avoid data comparing. Only structures should
-- be compared. Default - 0
-- 6. @NoTimestamp - flag, if set to 1, allows to avoid comparing of columns of timestamp
-- data type. Default - 0
-- 7. @VerboseLevel - if set to 1 allows to print querues used for data comparison
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Created by Viktor Gorodnichenko (c)
-- Created on: July 5, 2001
-- 060327 nbn: Changed 'Colimn' into 'column' & added "order by" to table listings.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROC sp_CompareDB
@db1 varchar(128),
@db2 varchar(128),
@OnlyStructure bit = 0,
@TabList varchar(8000) = '',
@NumbToShow int = 10,
@NoTimestamp bit = 0,
@VerboseLevel tinyint = 0
AS
if @OnlyStructure <> 0
set @OnlyStructure = 1
if @NoTimestamp <> 0
set @NoTimestamp = 1
if @VerboseLevel <> 0
set @VerboseLevel = 1

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
declare @sqlStr varchar(8000)
set nocount on
-- Checking if there are specified databases
declare @SrvName sysname
declare @DBName sysname
set @db1 = RTRIM(LTRIM(@db1))
set @db2 = RTRIM(LTRIM(@db2))
set @SrvName = @@SERVERNAME
if CHARINDEX('.',@db1) > 0
begin
set @SrvName = LEFT(@db1,CHARINDEX('.',@db1)-1)
if not exists (select * from master.dbo.sysservers where srvname = @SrvName)
begin
print 'There is no linked server named '+@SrvName+'. End of work.'
return 
end
set @DBName = RIGHT(@db1,LEN(@db1)-CHARINDEX('.',@db1))
end
else
set @DBName = @db1
exec ('declare @Name sysname select @Name=name from ['+@SrvName+'].master.dbo.sysdatabases where name = '''+@DBName+'''')
if @@rowcount = 0
begin
print 'There is no database named '+@db1+'. End of work.'
return 
end
set @SrvName = @@SERVERNAME
if CHARINDEX('.',@db2) > 0
begin
set @SrvName = LEFT(@db2,CHARINDEX('.',@db2)-1)
if not exists (select * from master.dbo.sysservers where srvname = @SrvName)
begin
print 'There is no linked server named '+@SrvName+'. End of work.'
return 
end
set @DBName = RIGHT(@db2,LEN(@db2)-CHARINDEX('.',@db2))
end
else
set @DBName = @db2
exec ('declare @Name sysname select @Name=name from ['+@SrvName+'].master.dbo.sysdatabases where name = '''+@DBName+'''')
if @@rowcount = 0
begin
print 'There is no database named '+@db2+'. End of work.'
return 
end

print Replicate('-',LEN(@db1)+LEN(@db2)+25)
print 'Comparing databases '+@db1+' and '+@db2
print Replicate('-',LEN(@db1)+LEN(@db2)+25)
print 'Options specified:'
print ' Compare only structures: '+CASE WHEN @OnlyStructure = 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
print ' List of tables to compare: '+CASE WHEN LEN(@TabList) = 0 THEN ' All tables' ELSE @TabList END
print ' Max number of different rows in each table to show: '+LTRIM(STR(@NumbToShow))
print ' Compare timestamp columns: '+CASE WHEN @NoTimestamp = 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
print ' Verbose level: '+CASE WHEN @VerboseLevel = 0 THEN 'Low' ELSE 'High' END

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Comparing structures
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print CHAR(10)+Replicate('-',36)
print 'Comparing structure of the databases'
print Replicate('-',36)
if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#TabToCheck%')
drop table #TabToCheck
create table #TabToCheck (name sysname)
declare @NextCommaPos int
if len(@TabList) > 0 
begin
while 1=1
begin
set @NextCommaPos = CHARINDEX(',',@TabList)
if @NextCommaPos = 0
begin
set @sqlstr = 'insert into #TabToCheck values('''+@TabList+''')'
exec (@sqlstr)
break
end
set @sqlstr = 'insert into #TabToCheck values('''+LEFT(@TabList,@NextCommaPos-1)+''')'
exec (@sqlstr)
set @TabList = RIGHT(@TabList,LEN(@TabList)-@NextCommaPos)
end
end
else -- then will check all tables
begin
exec ('insert into #TabToCheck select name from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects where type = ''U''')
exec ('insert into #TabToCheck select name from '+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects where type = ''U''')
end
-- First check if at least one table specified in @TabList exists in db1
exec ('declare @Name sysname select @Name=name from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects where name in (select * from #TabToCheck)')
if @@rowcount = 0
begin
print 'No tables in '+@db1+' to check. End of work.'
return
end
-- Check if tables existing in db1 are in db2 (all tables or specified in @TabList)
if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#TabNotInDB2%')
drop table #TabNotInDB2
create table #TabNotInDB2 (name sysname)
insert into #TabNotInDB2 
-- 060327 nbn: Added order by..
exec ('select name from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects d1o '+
'where name in (select * from #TabToCheck) and '+
' d1o.type = ''U'' and not exists '+
'(select * from '+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects d2o'+
' where d2o.type = ''U'' and d2o.name = d1o.name) order by name')
if @@rowcount > 0
begin
print CHAR(10)+'The table(s) exist in '+@db1+', but do not exist in '+@db2+':'
select * from #TabNotInDB2 
end
delete from #TabToCheck where name in (select * from #TabNotInDB2)
drop table #TabNotInDB2

if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#TabNotInDB1%')
drop table #TabNotInDB1
create table #TabNotInDB1 (name sysname)
insert into #TabNotInDB1 
-- 060327 nbn: Added order by..
exec ('select name from '+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects d1o '+
'where name in (select * from #TabToCheck) and '+
' d1o.type = ''U'' and not exists '+
'(select * from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects d2o'+
' where d2o.type = ''U'' and d2o.name = d1o.name) order by name')
if @@rowcount > 0
begin
print CHAR(10)+'The table(s) exist in '+@db2+', but do not exist in '+@db1+':'
select * from #TabNotInDB1 
end
delete from #TabToCheck where name in (select * from #TabNotInDB1)
drop table #TabNotInDB1
-- Comparing structures of tables existing in both dbs
print CHAR(10)+'Checking if there are tables existing in both databases having structural differences ...'+CHAR(10)
if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#DiffStructure%')
drop table #DiffStructure
create table #DiffStructure (name sysname)
set @sqlStr='
declare @TName1 sysname, @TName2 sysname, @CName1 sysname, @CName2 sysname,
@TypeName1 sysname, @TypeName2 sysname,
@CLen1 smallint, @CLen2 smallint, @Type1 sysname, @Type2 sysname, @PrevTName sysname
declare @DiffStructure bit
declare Diff cursor fast_forward for
select d1o.name, d2o.name, d1c.name, d2c.name, d1t.name, d2t.name,
d1c.length, d2c.length, d1c.type, d2c.type
from ('+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects d1o 
JOIN '+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects d2o2 ON d1o.name = d2o2.name and d1o.type = ''U'' --only tables in both dbs
and d1o.name in (select * from #TabToCheck)
JOIN '+@db1+'.dbo.syscolumns d1c ON d1o.id = d1c.id
JOIN '+@db1+'.dbo.systypes d1t ON d1c.xusertype = d1t.xusertype)
FULL JOIN ('+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects d2o 
JOIN '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects d1o2 ON d1o2.name = d2o.name and d2o.type = ''U'' --only tables in both dbs
and d2o.name in (select * from #TabToCheck)
JOIN '+@db2+'.dbo.syscolumns d2c ON d2c.id = d2o.id
JOIN '+@db2+'.dbo.systypes d2t ON d2c.xusertype = d2t.xusertype)
ON d1o.name = d2o.name and d1c.name = d2c.name
WHERE (not exists 
(select * from '+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects d2o2
JOIN '+@db2+'.dbo.syscolumns d2c2 ON d2o2.id = d2c2.id
JOIN '+@db2+'.dbo.systypes d2t2 ON d2c2.xusertype = d2t2.xusertype
where d2o2.type = ''U''
and d2o2.name = d1o.name 
and d2c2.name = d1c.name 
and d2t2.name = d1t.name
and d2c2.length = d1c.length)
OR not exists 
(select * from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects d1o2
JOIN '+@db1+'.dbo.syscolumns d1c2 ON d1o2.id = d1c2.id
JOIN '+@db1+'.dbo.systypes d1t2 ON d1c2.xusertype = d1t2.xusertype
where d1o2.type = ''U''
and d1o2.name = d2o.name 
and d1c2.name = d2c.name 
and d1t2.name = d2t.name
and d1c2.length = d2c.length))
order by coalesce(d1o.name,d2o.name), d1c.name
open Diff
fetch next from Diff into @TName1, @TName2, @CName1, @CName2, @TypeName1, @TypeName2,
@CLen1, @CLen2, @Type1, @Type2
set @PrevTName = ''''
set @DiffStructure = 0
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
if Coalesce(@TName1,@TName2) <> @PrevTName
begin
if @PrevTName <> '''' and @DiffStructure = 1
begin
insert into #DiffStructure values (@PrevTName)
set @DiffStructure = 0
end
set @PrevTName = Coalesce(@TName1,@TName2)
print @PrevTName
end
if @CName2 is null
print '' Column ''+RTRIM(@CName1)+'' not in '+@db2+'''
else
if @CName1 is null
print '' Column ''+RTRIM(@CName2)+'' not in '+@db1+'''
else
if @TypeName1 <> @TypeName2
print '' Column ''+RTRIM(@CName1)+'': in '+@db1+' - ''+RTRIM(@TypeName1)+'', in '+@db2+' - ''+RTRIM(@TypeName2)
else --the columns are not null(are in both dbs) and types are equal,then length are diff
print '' Column ''+RTRIM(@CName1)+'': in '+@db1+' - ''+RTRIM(@TypeName1)+''(''+
LTRIM(STR(CASE when @TypeName1=''nChar'' or @TypeName1 = ''nVarChar'' then @CLen1/2 else @CLen1 end))+
''), in '+@db2+' - ''+RTRIM(@TypeName2)+''(''+
LTRIM(STR(CASE when @TypeName1=''nChar'' or @TypeName1 = ''nVarChar'' then @CLen2/2 else @CLen2 end))+'')''
if @Type1 = @Type2
set @DiffStructure=@DiffStructure -- Do nothing. Cannot invert predicate
else
set @DiffStructure = 1
fetch next from Diff into @TName1, @TName2, @CName1, @CName2, @TypeName1, @TypeName2,
@CLen1, @CLen2, @Type1, @Type2
end
deallocate Diff
if @DiffStructure = 1
insert into #DiffStructure values (@PrevTName)
'
exec (@sqlStr)
if (select count(*) from #DiffStructure) > 0
begin
print CHAR(10)+'The table(s) have the same name and different structure in the databases:'
select distinct * from #DiffStructure 
delete from #TabToCheck where name in (select * from #DiffStructure)
end
else
print CHAR(10)+'There are no tables with the same name and structural differences in the databases'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(10)
if @OnlyStructure = 1
begin
print 'The option ''Only compare structures'' was specified. End of work.'
return
end
exec ('declare @Name sysname select @Name=d1o.name
from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects d1o, '+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects d2o 
where d1o.name = d2o.name and d1o.type = ''U'' and d2o.type = ''U''
and d1o.name not in (''dtproperties'') 
and d1o.name in (select * from #TabToCheck)')
if @@rowcount = 0
begin
print 'There are no tables with the same name and structure in the databases to compare. End of work.'
return
end


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Comparing data 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- ##CompareStr - will be used to pass comparing strings into dynamic script
-- to execute the string
if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '##CompareStr%')
drop table ##CompareStr
create table ##CompareStr (Ind int, CompareStr varchar(8000))

if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#DiffTables%')
drop table #DiffTables
create table #DiffTables (Name sysname)
if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#IdenticalTables%')
drop table #IdenticalTables
create table #IdenticalTables (Name sysname)
if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#EmptyTables%')
drop table #EmptyTables
create table #EmptyTables (Name sysname)
if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#NoPKTables%')
drop table #NoPKTables
create table #NoPKTables (Name sysname)

if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#IndList1%')
truncate table #IndList1
else 
create table #IndList1 (IndId int, IndStatus int,
KeyAndStr varchar(7000), KeyCommaStr varchar(1000))
if exists (select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects where name like '#IndList2%')
truncate table #IndList2
else
create table #IndList2 (IndId smallint, IndStatus int,
KeyAndStr varchar(7000), KeyCommaStr varchar(1000))

print Replicate('-',51)
print 'Comparing data in tables with indentical structure:'
print Replicate('-',51)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Cursor for all tables in dbs (or for all specified tables if parameter @TabList is passed)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @SqlStrGetListOfKeys1 varchar(8000)
declare @SqlStrGetListOfKeys2 varchar(8000)
declare @SqlStrGetListOfColumns varchar(8000)
declare @SqlStrCompareUKeyTables varchar(8000)
declare @SqlStrCompareNonUKeyTables varchar(8000)
set @SqlStrGetListOfKeys1 = '
declare @sqlStr varchar(8000)
declare @ExecSqlStr varchar(8000)
declare @PrintSqlStr varchar(8000)
declare @Tab varchar(128)
declare @d1User varchar(128)
declare @d2User varchar(128)
declare @KeyAndStr varchar(8000) 
declare @KeyCommaStr varchar(8000) 
declare @AndStr varchar(8000) 
declare @Eq varchar(8000) 
declare @IndId int
declare @IndStatus int
declare @CurrIndId smallint
declare @CurrStatus int
declare @UKey sysname 
declare @Col varchar(128)
declare @LastUsedCol varchar(128)
declare @xType int
declare @Len int
declare @SelectStr varchar(8000) 
declare @ExecSql nvarchar(1000) 
declare @NotInDB1 bit 
declare @NotInDB2 bit 
declare @NotEq bit 
declare @Numb int
declare @Cnt1 int
declare @Cnt2 int
set @Numb = 0

declare @StrInd int
declare @i int
declare @PrintStr varchar(8000)
declare @ExecStr varchar(8000)
declare TabCur cursor for 

select d1o.name, d1u.name, d2u.name from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects d1o, '+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects d2o,
'+@db1+'.dbo.sysusers d1u, '+@db2+'.dbo.sysusers d2u 
where d1o.name = d2o.name and d1o.type = ''U'' and d2o.type = ''U''
and d1o.uid = d1u.uid and d2o.uid = d2u.uid 
and d1o.name not in (''dtproperties'') 
and d1o.name in (select * from #TabToCheck)
order by 1

open TabCur 
fetch next from TabCur into @Tab, @d1User, @d2User 
while @@fetch_status = 0 
begin 
set @Numb = @Numb + 1
print Char(13)+Char(10)+LTRIM(STR(@Numb))+''. TABLE: [''+@Tab+''] ''

set @ExecSql = ''SELECT @Cnt = count(*) FROM '+@db1+'.[''+@d1User+''].[''+@Tab+'']''
exec sp_executesql @ExecSql, N''@Cnt int output'', @Cnt = @Cnt1 output
print CHAR(10)+STR(@Cnt1)+'' rows in '+@db1+'''
set @ExecSql = ''SELECT @Cnt = count(*) FROM '+@db2+'.[''+@d2User+''].[''+@Tab+'']''
exec sp_executesql @ExecSql, N''@Cnt int output'', @Cnt = @Cnt2 output
print STR(@Cnt2)+'' rows in '+@db2+'''
if @Cnt1 = 0 and @Cnt2 = 0
begin
exec ('' insert into #EmptyTables values(''''[''+@Tab+'']'''')'') 
goto NextTab
end
set @KeyAndStr = '''' 
set @KeyCommaStr = '''' 
set @NotInDB1 = 0
set @NotInDB2 = 0 
set @NotEq = 0
set @KeyAndStr = '''' 
set @KeyCommaStr = '''' 
truncate table #IndList1
declare UKeys cursor fast_forward for 
select i.indid, i.status, c.name, c.xType from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects o, '+@db1+'.dbo.sysindexes i, '+@db1+'.dbo.sysindexkeys k, '+@db1+'.dbo.syscolumns c 
where i.id = o.id and o.name = @Tab
and (i.status & 2)<>0 
and k.id = o.id and k.indid = i.indid 
and c.id = o.id and c.colid = k.colid 
order by i.indid, c.name
open UKeys 
fetch next from UKeys into @IndId, @IndStatus, @UKey, @xType
set @CurrIndId = @IndId
set @CurrStatus = @IndStatus
while @@fetch_status = 0 
begin 
if @KeyAndStr <> ''''
begin 
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' and '' + CHAR(10) 
set @KeyCommaStr = @KeyCommaStr + '', '' 
end 
if @xType = 175 or @xType = 167 or @xType = 239 or @xType = 231 -- char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' ISNULL(d1.[''+@UKey+''],''''!#null$'''')=ISNULL(d2.[''+@UKey+''],''''!#null$'''') ''
end
if @xType = 173 or @xType = 165 -- binary, varbinary
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr +
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 0x4D4FFB23A49411D5BDDB00A0C906B7B4 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 0x4D4FFB23A49411D5BDDB00A0C906B7B4 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 56 or @xType = 127 or @xType = 60 or @xType = 122 -- int, 127 - bigint,60 - money, 122 - smallmoney
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + 
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 971428763405345098745 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 971428763405345098745 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 106 or @xType = 108 -- int, decimal, numeric
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + 
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 71428763405345098745098.8723 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 71428763405345098745098.8723 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 62 or @xType = 59 -- 62 - float, 59 - real
begin 
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + 
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 8764589764.22708E237 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 8764589764.22708E237 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 52 or @xType = 48 or @xType = 104 -- smallint, tinyint, bit
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 99999 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 99999 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 36 -- 36 - id 
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr +
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null''+
'' THEN CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,''''1CD827A0-744A-4866-8401-B9902CF2D4FB'''')''+
'' ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null''+
'' THEN CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,''''1CD827A0-744A-4866-8401-B9902CF2D4FB'''')''+
'' ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END''
end
else if @xType = 61 or @xType = 58 -- datetime, smalldatetime
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr +
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN ''''!#null$'''' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(40),d1.[''+@UKey+''],109) END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN ''''!#null$'''' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(40),d2.[''+@UKey+''],109) END ''
end
else if @xType = 189 -- timestamp (189) 
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' d1.[''+@UKey+'']=d2.[''+@UKey+''] ''
end
else if @xType = 98 -- SQL_variant
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' ISNULL(d1.[''+@UKey+''],''''!#null$'''')=ISNULL(d2.[''+@UKey+''],''''!#null$'''') ''
end
set @KeyCommaStr = @KeyCommaStr + '' d1.''+@UKey 
fetch next from UKeys into @IndId, @IndStatus, @UKey, @xType
if @IndId <> @CurrIndId
begin
insert into #IndList1 values (@CurrIndId, @CurrStatus, @KeyAndStr, @KeyCommaStr)
set @CurrIndId = @IndId
set @CurrStatus = @IndStatus
set @KeyAndStr = ''''
set @KeyCommaStr = '''' 
end
end 
deallocate UKeys 
insert into #IndList1 values (@CurrIndId, @CurrStatus, @KeyAndStr, @KeyCommaStr)'
set @SqlStrGetListOfKeys2 = '
set @KeyAndStr = '''' 
set @KeyCommaStr = '''' 
truncate table #IndList2
declare UKeys cursor fast_forward for 
select i.indid, i.status, c.name, c.xType from '+@db2+'.dbo.sysobjects o, '+@db2+'.dbo.sysindexes i, '+@db2+'.dbo.sysindexkeys k, '+@db2+'.dbo.syscolumns c 
where i.id = o.id and o.name = @Tab
and (i.status & 2)<>0 
and k.id = o.id and k.indid = i.indid 
and c.id = o.id and c.colid = k.colid 
order by i.indid, c.name
open UKeys 
fetch next from UKeys into @IndId, @IndStatus, @UKey, @xType
set @CurrIndId = @IndId
set @CurrStatus = @IndStatus
while @@fetch_status = 0 
begin 
if @KeyAndStr <> ''''
begin 
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' and '' + CHAR(10) 
set @KeyCommaStr = @KeyCommaStr + '', '' 
end 
if @xType = 175 or @xType = 167 or @xType = 239 or @xType = 231 -- char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' ISNULL(d1.[''+@UKey+''],''''!#null$'''')=ISNULL(d2.[''+@UKey+''],''''!#null$'''') ''
end
if @xType = 173 or @xType = 165 -- binary, varbinary
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr +
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 0x4D4FFB23A49411D5BDDB00A0C906B7B4 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 0x4D4FFB23A49411D5BDDB00A0C906B7B4 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 56 or @xType = 127 or @xType = 60 or @xType = 122 -- int, 127 - bigint,60 - money, 122 - smallmoney
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + 
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 971428763405345098745 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 971428763405345098745 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 106 or @xType = 108 -- int, decimal, numeric
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + 
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 71428763405345098745098.8723 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 71428763405345098745098.8723 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 62 or @xType = 59 -- 62 - float, 59 - real
begin 
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + 
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 8764589764.22708E237 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 8764589764.22708E237 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 52 or @xType = 48 or @xType = 104 -- smallint, tinyint, bit
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 99999 ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN 99999 ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 36 -- 36 - id 
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr +
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null''+
'' THEN CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,''''1CD827A0-744A-4866-8401-B9902CF2D4FB'''')''+
'' ELSE d1.[''+@UKey+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null''+
'' THEN CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,''''1CD827A0-744A-4866-8401-B9902CF2D4FB'''')''+
'' ELSE d2.[''+@UKey+''] END''
end
else if @xType = 61 or @xType = 58 -- datetime, smalldatetime
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr +
'' CASE WHEN d1.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN ''''!#null$'''' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(40),d1.[''+@UKey+''],109) END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@UKey+''] is null THEN ''''!#null$'''' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(40),d2.[''+@UKey+''],109) END ''
end
else if @xType = 189 -- timestamp (189) 
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' d1.[''+@UKey+'']=d2.[''+@UKey+''] ''
end
else if @xType = 98 -- SQL_variant
begin
set @KeyAndStr = @KeyAndStr + '' ISNULL(d1.[''+@UKey+''],''''!#null$'''')=ISNULL(d2.[''+@UKey+''],''''!#null$'''') ''
end
set @KeyCommaStr = @KeyCommaStr + '' d1.''+@UKey 
fetch next from UKeys into @IndId, @IndStatus, @UKey, @xType
if @IndId <> @CurrIndId
begin
insert into #IndList2 values (@CurrIndId, @CurrStatus, @KeyAndStr, @KeyCommaStr)
set @CurrIndId = @IndId
set @CurrStatus = @IndStatus
set @KeyAndStr = ''''
set @KeyCommaStr = '''' 
end
end 
deallocate UKeys 
insert into #IndList2 values (@CurrIndId, @CurrStatus, @KeyAndStr, @KeyCommaStr)
set @KeyCommaStr = null

select @KeyCommaStr=i1.KeyCommaStr from #IndList1 i1
join #IndList2 i2 on i1.KeyCommaStr = i2.KeyCommaStr
where (i1.IndStatus & 2048)<> 0 and (i2.IndStatus & 2048)<>0

if @KeyCommaStr is null 
set @KeyCommaStr = (select top 1 i1.KeyCommaStr from #IndList1 i1
join #IndList2 i2 on i1.KeyCommaStr = i2.KeyCommaStr)
set @KeyAndStr = (select TOP 1 KeyAndStr from #IndList1 where KeyCommaStr = @KeyCommaStr)
if @KeyCommaStr is null
set @KeyCommaStr = ''''
if @KeyAndStr is null
set @KeyAndStr = '''''
set @SqlStrGetListOfColumns = '
set @AndStr = ''''
set @StrInd = 1
declare Cols cursor local fast_forward for 
select c.name, c.xtype, c.length from '+@db1+'.dbo.sysobjects o, '+@db1+'.dbo.syscolumns c
where o.id = c.id and o.name = @Tab 
and CHARINDEX(c.name, @KeyCommaStr) = 0
open Cols 
fetch next from Cols into @Col, @xType, @len
while @@fetch_status = 0 
begin 
if @xType = 175 or @xType = 167 or @xType = 239 or @xType = 231 -- char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar
begin
set @Eq = ''ISNULL(d1.[''+@Col+''],''''!#null$'''')=ISNULL(d2.[''+@Col+''],''''!#null$'''') ''
end
if @xType = 173 or @xType = 165 -- binary, varbinary
begin
set @Eq = ''CASE WHEN d1.[''+@Col+''] is null THEN 0x4D4FFB23A49411D5BDDB00A0C906B7B4 ELSE d1.[''+@Col+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@Col+''] is null THEN 0x4D4FFB23A49411D5BDDB00A0C906B7B4 ELSE d2.[''+@Col+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 56 or @xType = 127 or @xType = 60 or @xType = 122 -- int, 127 - bigint,60 - money, 122 - smallmoney
begin
set @Eq = ''CASE WHEN d1.[''+@Col+''] is null THEN 971428763405345098745 ELSE d1.[''+@Col+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@Col+''] is null THEN 971428763405345098745 ELSE d2.[''+@Col+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 106 or @xType = 108 -- int, decimal, numeric
begin
set @Eq = ''CASE WHEN d1.[''+@Col+''] is null THEN 71428763405345098745098.8723 ELSE d1.[''+@Col+''] END=''+
''CASE WHEN d2.[''+@Col+''] is null THEN 71428763405345098745098.8723 ELSE d2.[''+@Col+''] END ''
end
else if @xType = 62 or @xType = 59 -- 62 - float, 59 - real
begin 
set @Eq = ''CASE WHEN d1.[''+@Col+'']
```

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you script the entire database you want to have. Use this script as a single place that defines the architecture of your database. Immediate purpose of it will be to create identical databases on both servers and in the long run you can maintain that script to reflect the structure. After that just create your new databases and copy the data from old database(s) to the new one.

Comment: i dont think that will work well. cause i hae different changes in both databases. And im not sure if i know all of them. cant i write a stored proc that actually scans on both servers and if key = match then select insert else create new (something on these lines)

Comment: No, I'm only suggesting you define the database that will contain the result of merging as a script and maintain it. It will be much more helpful than a script that is automatically generate by SQL Server. After you defined how you want your data to be it is despite non-trivial in some places, but straightforward task to pull the data from existing databases to this new one. Whether you want to script this process is up to the personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

First, stop making any more differences between the two!

Next, sort out the tables incompatibilities. Script out all the tables, constraints, and views for each database and do a `DIFF` to see what structural issue you will have combining the data. If you use `identities`, you will need to address how to mix the data.  Are there views that are named the same, but have with different results?  You need to decide how to handle those.  You can make incremental changes to one of the databases that will make it more compatible with the other, and/or you could plan on a massive conversion script.

When you get a handle on that, build a new schema that can contain both databases.  From there worry about stored procedure and business logic, using the same `DIFF` approach.